# Dose any gpu version of GaussianBlur in Opencv-3.4.5

Tags: c++, opencv, graph, gpu

I am using ***opencv-3.4.5*** now,

but I want to use GPU to accelerate my GaussianBlur, Canny, and findContours API.

I know there is gpu::GaussianBlur in ***opencv-2.4.13.7***,

they have namespace GPU to accelerate processing graph.

> [opencv-2.4.13.7 GPU](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/image_filtering.html?highlight=blur)

On the other hand, opencv-3.4.5 suppot namespace **cuda** for gpu,

but I didn't see any API like gpu::GaussianBlur,which I can use.

> [opencv-3.4.5 CUDA](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d1a/namespacecv_1_1cuda.html)

I found a website to compare Opencv API performance use GPU or not.

> [opencv GPU performance comparison](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/opencv-3-4-gpu-cuda-performance-comparison-nvidia-vs-intel/)

My question is does any GaussianBlur API for GPU in opencv-3.4.5,

or other way I can used to accelerate it.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d66/group__cudafilters.html#gaa4df286369114cfd4b144ae211f6a6c8 Did you take a look at this?

Comment: is this equal to GaussianBlur, but in GPU compare web, there compare lots of opencv API, not only GaussianBlur,how about others.

Comment: I think mathematics is the same, although you might have to add a few more steps. Again, not sure. About the rest, you have to explore namespace "cuda".